# How to release an App only for iPhone devices?

Tags: ios

I have seen this question is repeated numerous number of times but non of the solution worked for me.

My app has been rejected because of:

> 2.10 Details
>
> We noticed that several screens of your app were crowded or laid our
>   in a way that made it difficult to use your app on iPad running iOS
>   9.0.2, which is a violation of the App Store Review Guidelines. We’ve attached screenshot(s) for your reference.

But I followed all solutions on SO:

[image]

[image]

Some solution said I must change something `UIDeviceFamily` in `info.plist` 
but I don't have such a field in this file.

Beside this, some solution said set the `UIRequiredDeviceCapabilities` stating that the app requires telephony. But my app dose not need telephony.

Comment: What's the question?  Does setting *Devices* to *iPhone* not solve your problem?

Comment: I already set setting as above but I got rejected from apple with above reason. What else I should do to get my app approved?

Comment: Nothing else should be required within Xcode.  Is there anything in iTunes Connect?

Comment: You need to test your app on an iPad or at least an iPad simulator.  iPhone apps run at iPhone 4 resolution on an iPad and you can't prevent this, so the chances are your layout isn't correct in this case.  You may also have a poor UI on iPhone 4 if you haven't tested that since that is the screen size used on iPad for an iPhone app.

Answer (score -1):

Maybe others identifier let them think your app support iPad? For example,When you set the project as iPhone app,you can also choice some set for the iPad.Did they judge your app from something like this.You can see the screenshot,It is just a guess.I am a new guy.[image]